# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 ImageMagick on Mac Lion

Tags: imagemagick

On Mac Lion I have done a configure, make and install a static version of ImageMagick. All went fine and as result of configure I get

```
configuring ImageMagick 6.7.2-4
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0
....
```

But when I am trying to use the static library in my own application, the linker send me hundreds of link error such as...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_XOpenDisplay", referenced from:
      _RenderType in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_la-annotate.o)
      _DisplayImages in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_la-display.o)
...

"_XInitImage", referenced from:
      _ReadXWDImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_la-xwd.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Here is my LIBS declaration

```
LIBS += -L/Library/ImageMagick-6.7.2-4/magick/.libs \
  -L/Library/ImageMagick-6.7.2-4/magick \
  -L/Library/ImageMagick-6.7.2-4/wand/.libs \
  -L/Library/ImageMagick-6.7.2-4/wand \
  -L/usr/X11/lib \
  -R/usr/X11/lib \
  -L/opt/local/lib \
  -L/opt/lib \
  -lMagick++ \
  -lMagickCore \
  -lMagickWand  \
  -ltiff \
  -lfreetype \
  -ljpeg \
  -ljasper -lpng14 -lbz2 -lz -lm -lpthread
```

I am not really sure what is going wrong or what is missing.

Comment: The undefined symbols are from the X Window System. Have you tried to run `configure` with the `--without-x` option?

Answer (score 0):

This is a compile problem as `XOpenDisplay` is apart of `X`. Simply include the library `-lX11` in your LIBS declaration.

```
LIBS += -L/Library/ImageMagick-6.7.2-4/magick/.libs \
  -L/Library/ImageMagick-6.7.2-4/magick \
  -L/Library/ImageMagick-6.7.2-4/wand/.libs \
  -L/Library/ImageMagick-6.7.2-4/wand \
  -L/usr/X11/lib \
  -R/usr/X11/lib \
  -L/opt/local/lib \
  -L/opt/lib \
  -lX11 \
  -lMagick++ \
  -lMagickCore \
  -lMagickWand  \
  -ltiff \
  -lfreetype \
  -ljpeg \
  -ljasper -lpng14 -lbz2 -lz -lm -lpthread
```