# How to successfully integrate ImageMagick into iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, imagemagick

I currently have a linker error, roughly 44 references to undefined symbols for the architecture x86_64.  All of them are from an integrated file "libMagickCore.a" so I attempted to search for solutions to "undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 libmagickcore.a"
I have seen a solution here [Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 ImageMagick on Mac Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406533/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-imagemagick-on-mac-lion) which addresses a similar issue on Mac Lion.  I have also looked on ImageMagick boards for similar issues.  The threads that I found and the Stack Overflow link seem to talk about including or explicitly excluding an X11 library.

I attempted to add "-lX11" to "Other Linker Flags" under build settings, but I end up with "library not found for -lX11."  Because of this, I also tried dragging libX11.dylib from /opt/X11/lib into my XCode Project to no avail.  Suggestions for similar issues on the ImageMagick boards are to use a "--without-wmf" "--without-x11" flag, but I do not know which key/value pair of the build settings to add that to without a compiler error saying "unsupported option."

Theses are the linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_xmlAddAttributeDecl", referenced from:
      _MSLAttributeDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGAttributeDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlAddChild", referenced from:
      _MSLReference in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _MSLCDataBlock in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGReference in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
      _SVGCDataBlock in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlAddDocEntity", referenced from:
      _MSLEntityDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _MSLUnparsedEntityDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGEntityDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
      _SVGUnparsedEntityDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlAddDtdEntity", referenced from:
      _MSLEntityDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGEntityDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlAddElementDecl", referenced from:
      _MSLElementDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGElementDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlAddNotationDecl", referenced from:
      _MSLNotationDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGNotationDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlCleanupParser", referenced from:
      _UnregisterMSLImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _UnregisterSVGImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlCreateIntSubset", referenced from:
      _MSLInternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGInternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlCreatePushParserCtxt", referenced from:
      _ProcessMSLScript in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _ReadSVGImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlDetectCharEncoding", referenced from:
      _MSLExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlFree", referenced from:
      _MSLAttributeDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _MSLExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGAttributeDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
      _SVGExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
      _ReadURLImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-url.o)
  "_xmlFreeDoc", referenced from:
      _SVGEndDocument in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlFreeInputStream", referenced from:
      _MSLExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlFreeParserCtxt", referenced from:
      _ProcessMSLScript in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _ReadSVGImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlGetDocEntity", referenced from:
      _MSLGetEntity in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGGetEntity in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlGetLastChild", referenced from:
      _MSLCDataBlock in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGCDataBlock in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlGetParameterEntity", referenced from:
      _MSLGetParameterEntity in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGGetParameterEntity in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlInitParser", referenced from:
      _RegisterMSLImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _RegisterSVGImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlLoadExternalEntity", referenced from:
      _MSLResolveEntity in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGResolveEntity in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlMalloc", referenced from:
      _MSLExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlNanoFTPClose", referenced from:
      _ReadURLImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-url.o)
  "_xmlNanoFTPConnect", referenced from:
      _ReadURLImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-url.o)
  "_xmlNanoFTPGet", referenced from:
      _ReadURLImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-url.o)
  "_xmlNanoFTPInit", referenced from:
      _ReadURLImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-url.o)
  "_xmlNanoFTPNewCtxt", referenced from:
      _ReadURLImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-url.o)
  "_xmlNanoHTTPCleanup", referenced from:
      _ReadURLImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-url.o)
  "_xmlNanoHTTPClose", referenced from:
      _ReadURLImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-url.o)
  "_xmlNanoHTTPMethod", referenced from:
      _ReadURLImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-url.o)
  "_xmlNanoHTTPRead", referenced from:
      _ReadURLImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-url.o)
  "_xmlNewCDataBlock", referenced from:
      _MSLCDataBlock in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGCDataBlock in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlNewCharRef", referenced from:
      _MSLReference in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGReference in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlNewDoc", referenced from:
      _MSLStartDocument in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGStartDocument in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlNewDtd", referenced from:
      _MSLExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlNewReference", referenced from:
      _MSLReference in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGReference in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlParseChunk", referenced from:
      _ProcessMSLScript in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _ReadSVGImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlParseExternalSubset", referenced from:
      _MSLExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlPopInput", referenced from:
      _MSLExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlPushInput", referenced from:
      _MSLExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlSplitQName", referenced from:
      _MSLAttributeDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGAttributeDeclaration in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlStrdup", referenced from:
      _MSLStartDocument in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _MSLExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGStartDocument in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
      _SVGExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlSubstituteEntitiesDefault", referenced from:
      _ProcessMSLScript in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _ReadSVGImage in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlSwitchEncoding", referenced from:
      _MSLExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGExternalSubset in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
  "_xmlTextConcat", referenced from:
      _MSLCDataBlock in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-msl.o)
      _SVGCDataBlock in libMagickCore.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-svg.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Those errors are from some missing XML library, not X11.

Comment: Well if you look at this link: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=19467
There are some xml references, and I believe some of them are the same.  Some guy said the solution was to use the --without-x11 flag somewhere, though I do not know which key/value flag to add that to.  I tried the linker flag key to no avail

Comment: I've never tried to build ImageMagick. I have no idea what the fix is. I'm simply pointing out that the missing symbols posted in your question are from some XML library you aren't including. And they are all coming from code related to MSL and SVG (based on the what is referencing the XML code).

Comment: Right, and in the ImageMagick board link, it seems to have the same MSL/SVG things in there.  Perhaps it is X11 that I need to include/exclude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adding "libxml2.2.tbd" to the project by going to "Build Phases" and Link Binary with Libraries.